# SQL subquery inside FROM and WHERE class

Tags: sql, join, subquery

Can you please help me out understand why the code below does not work?

Basically, there are two tables - `Economies` and `Countries`. From the `Countries` table, I need to find get a list of country codes which are not constitutional monarchies or republic.

And then using these codes I need to extract the inflation rate and unemployment rate parameters from economies using the above criteria.

This is my SQL code:

```
SELECT 
    e.code, e.inflation_rate, e.unemployment_rate, subquery.gov_form
FROM
    ECONOMIES e,
    (SELECT code, gov_form
     FROM countries
     WHERE gov_form NOT IN ('Constitutional Monarchy', 'Republic')         
    ) AS subquery
WHERE 
    year = 2015 
    AND code IN (SELECT code FROM subquery)
```

On line 9, I get an error

> Relation subquery does not exist

I know this can be performed using JOINS but I want to understand why this code does not work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea what useful thing you are trying to do.  However your *syntax* problem is arising because you are confusing subqueries with CTE, tables, and views.  The latter can all be referenced multiple times in a query.

So, you seem to want:

```
WITH subquery AS (
      SELECT code, gov_form
      FROM countries
      WHERE gov_form NOT IN ('Constitutional Monarchy','Republic' )  
     )
SELECT e.code, e.inflation_rate, e.unemployment_rate, subquery.gov_form
FROM ECONOMIES e CROSS JOIN
     subquery
WHERE year = 2015 AND
      e.code IN (SELECT s.code FROM subquery s);
```

I suspect, though, that you just want `JOIN`:

```
SELECT e.code, e.inflation_rate, e.unemployment_rate, c.gov_form
FROM ECONOMIES e JOIN
     countries c
     ON e.code = c.code
WHERE year = 2015 AND
       c.gov_form NOT IN ('Constitutional Monarchy', 'Republic');
```

At the very least, this does something sensible.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to select from subquery, which is not a table, but a relation generated by a query. Fix:

```
SELECT 
    e.code, e.inflation_rate, e.unemployment_rate, subquery.gov_form
FROM
    ECONOMIES e,
    JOIN (SELECT code, gov_form
     FROM countries
     WHERE gov_form NOT IN ('Constitutional Monarchy', 'Republic')         
    ) AS subquery
    ON e.year = subquery.year AND year = 2015 AND
    e.code = subquery.code
```